# Is anyone able to prevent "overscroll" in iOS PWAs that are "Added to Home Screen"?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, overscroll

I've tried everything, including:

```
(() => {
    const prevent = e => e.preventDefault();
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', prevent, { passive: false });
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', prevent, { passive: false });
})()

overscroll-behavior: contain;
touch-action: none;
```

Nothing seems to be working. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Could you provide the logs?